# When searching the data from the oracle table gives following exception

Tags: java, spring, oracle, mybatis

I am using Spring Framework, MyBatis, Oracle. This issue is coming only in production. It's working fine in lower environments.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator - Unable to translate SQLException with Error code '17027', will now try the fallback translator
DEBUG [2020-08-24 00:19:20,536] [dw-24 - /oms/templateSummary/details - POST /oms/templateSummary/details] org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator - Extracted SQL state class '99' from value '99999'
ERROR [2020-08-24 00:19:20,537] [dw-24 - /oms/templateSummary/details - POST /oms/templateSummary/details] biz.neustar.omsuiapp.resource.TemplateManagementHistory - templateOrderSummaryList(): Error occurs due to :
ERROR [2020-08-24 00:19:20,538] [dw-24 - /oms/templateSummary/details - POST /oms/templateSummary/details] biz.neustar.omsuiapp.exception.OMSUIServiceException - Exception occurs due to : Error occurred while performing search.
DEBUG [2020-08-24 00:19:20,540] [dw-24 - /oms/templateSummary/details - POST /oms/templateSummary/details] 

 org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.mapTargetToRuntimeEx(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:199) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.access$200(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:74) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:169) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:181) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:101) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:305) ~[jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110) [jersey-server-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.17.jar:na]
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83) [jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:300) [jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipFilter.doFilter(BiDiGzipFilter.java:134) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:29) [dropwizard-servlets-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44) [dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39) [dropwizard-jersey-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:259) [jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:222) [jetty-servlets-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240) [metrics-jetty9-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51) [dropwizard-jetty-0.8.1.jar:0.8.1]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:95) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.9.v20150224.jar:9.2.9.v20150224]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
```

Comment: Hi. please take the [tour] and maybe read [ask].  You need to post some sort of [mcve].  Hard to help with just  a stack dump.

Comment: If error code is ORA-17027, documentation says that it means "Stream has already been closed". Though, I have no idea what it means, I don't know Java (and I'm not sorry about it).

Comment: There's nothing related to MyBatis in the exception. Looks like a simple Oracle error. Why do you think it is?